# nginx default error page stopped working for some reason

Tags: nginx, 502-error

This used to work:

```
server {
  server_name example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
    error_page 502 /502.html;
  }

  location = /502.html {
    root /var/www/example;
  }
}
```

Now suddenly it doesn't anymore... I don't know what changed ?

I get 404 instead of displayed `/var/www/example/index.html` in case port 8888 doesn't respond...

How to make this work again?
thank you

Comment: You mean `/var/www/example/502.html` rather than `/var/www/example/index.html`? Is that just a typo?

Comment: Please see the reply below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The majority of your content lives on the remote server. You need to serve an error page (together with some resources) locally. You need a "special location" which is distinct from any location served from upstream, and put all of your local resources in there. I can't pick a name for that location, as I have no idea what you are serving from 8888. But lets say `/error_pages` for now.

```
server {
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
        error_page 502 /error_pages/502.html;
    }

    location /error_pages {
        root /var/www/example;
    }
}
```

With the above configuration, you will need to edit `502.html` and change the URLs of the resources to add the `/error_pages` prefix.

You will also need to move all of the files (`502.html` and its resource files) into `/var/www/example/error_pages/` subdirectory.

Comment: Thank you, but is there no way to serve something that is actually not an error page? Imagine I want to serve something from my local machine via SSH forwarding on port 8888.. but when this is not active, I just want to show regular page (so semantically this is not an error page)... can I somehow reuse the normal page like `index.html` without changing any of its resources? Exactly this magically worked before now I really don't know why or how anymore and I didn't change my configuration, just doesn't work as it used to...

Comment: ok maybe it is not possible... I did as you said, and I have it working but with duplication of resources inside `error_pages` folder... I don't really like it but I guess I'll have to

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration states that the error document is `/var/www/example/502.html`. Nothing in your configuration attempts to load `/var/www/example/index.html` at any time, ever. Rename the file.

Comment: First: I assure you this exact configuration worked some time ago (it somehow served index.html from that dir correctly although it's not specified), I agree it's strange.. but I have also tried to copy `index.html` into `502.html` and then the page displays but all resources (img, css) are not visible, because there is 502 on them... see `bitcells.com` please.. this is now serving 502.html and images are missing... so what would be the complete code to make this work? thank you

Comment: http://cl.ly/3N1r0J1a1O0b